# How to calculate number of users who did multiple events in big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I tried using JOIN function but not sure if that is the right/smart way to do it.

I want to know the number of users who did "first_open" and "BA_HOME"SCREEN" in particular time period.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Let's say there are two events - "first_open" and "BA_HOME_SCREEN". Now, i want to know how many users are there who did these two events in July month. We have user_id which is unique for every user

Answer (score 0):

You provided following dataset:

| Date | event_name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05052021 | first_open | 123 |
| 25052021 | ba_home | 435 |

The goal is to count the occurrences of two different strings in the column `event_name` in two separated columns for each `user_id`.
This can be done with the `pivot` statement:

```
Select *
from (
Select "a" as user_id, "first_open" as event_name
Union all select "b" ,  "BA_HOME_SCREEN"
Union all select "b" ,  "first_open"
)
PIVOT(count(1) FOR event_name IN ("first_open", "BA_HOME_SCREEN"))
```

see [big query references](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator)

Another approche would be to use a `case` statement (an `if` statement would be possible as well):

```
select user_id, sum(case when event_name="first_open" then 1 else 0 end) as first_open
from ( ..... )
group by 1
```

Comment: This is how dataset looks like - 

Date           | event_name | user_id 
05052021     first_open        123
25052021     ba_home          435
.
.
.
.